# Getting the value of a forms.ChoiceField instead of the label, from the view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a FormView from which I'd like to do a bit of form processing.

Within the `form_valid()` I'm trying to obtain the submitted form's values in order to instantiate a different object.

When I get the `form.cleaned_data` however, I am returned a dictionary of `{'form field name' : 'choice label'}`.
I'd like to get the value corresponding to the choice label.

Here is the FormView--the `get_form_kwargs` bit is simple passing custom choices to the view:

```
class RequestView(FormView):
    form_class = RequestForm
    template_name = 'profile/request.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        requester_obj = Profile.objects.get(
            user__username=self.request.user)
        accepter_obj = Profile.objects.get(
            user__username=self.kwargs.get('username'))

        r_favorite_set = requester_obj.get_favorite()
        a_favorite_set = accepter_obj.get_favorite()

        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()

        kwargs['your_favorite'] = r_favorite_set
        kwargs['their_favorite'] = a_favorite_set

        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        super(RequestView, self).form_valid(form)

        # I've tried get_FOO_display() extra instance method
        print(form.get_your_favorite_display())

        # The following will return the choice label
        print(form.cleaned_data.get('your_favorite'))

        Favorites.objects.create(#need form choice selections)

        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Code explanation: Within the `form_valid` I hope to create a different object using the selection from the submitted form.

So how do I get the submitted choice instead of the label? Is this even the proper place to do this?

edit: The Form:

```
class RequestForm(forms.Form):
    your_favorite = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[],
        widget=RadioSelect,
        required=True,
        label="What would you like to exchange?"  
    )
    their_favorite = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=RadioSelect,
        required=False,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        your_choices = kwargs.pop('your_favorite')
        their_choices = kwargs.pop('their_favorite')

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['your_favorite'].choices = your_choices
        self.fields['their_favorite'].choices = their_choices
```

edit2:

```
def get_favorite(self):
        return (('a', self.fave1), ('b', self.fave2), ('c', self.fave3))
```

**edit3:**

...So I could've just done this all along.

```
def get_favorite(self):
        return ((self.fave1, self.fave1), (self.fave2, self.fave2), (self.fave3, self.fave3))
```

**BUT** this causes some really funky behavior in the form. For some reason this causes a radio to be selected by default with every GET request to the form view. It will select the third choice to be selected if all the options are "None", or the first option to be selected if only the first is "None".
Anyway, this may be a question for a separate post.

Comment: You need to show the code for RequestForm. What's it doing with those kwargs?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry for late edit. It is up now.

Comment: Still not enough information, I'm afraid. What does the `get_favorite()` method do?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added `get_favorite()`, which is a model method that simple returns a tuple of model properties, and is according to django's requirements for Choices. I use these properties to pre-populate the ChoiceField.

Comment: So are `self.fave1` etc the values you want to get in the view? What are you getting instead?

Comment: I am getting fave1,2,3 in my template through the view as expected. 1,2,3 are the choices i am presenting on the form. I am now attempting to obtain the user's selection from these choices, upon form submission.

Comment: But what is `form.cleaned_data.get('your_favorite')` giving you instead?

Comment: cleaned_data returns a dictionary, and .get('your_favorite') (the value) will return the Choice's label--which in this instance, is 'a', 'b' or 'c' as indicated on my edit2.

Comment: I wish you would show real code. Choices are in the form (id, label) so the first value is what is returned and the second one is what is displayed. So, exactly what are you showing on the form and what are you getting in your view?

Comment: Sorry--I edited code slightly to be as bare-bones as possible for readability. I've simply removed a "label" attribute from `forms.ChoiceField` which I'll add now.  If I flip this: `('a', self.fave1),` around, then on the form it will simply display 'a' to the user. I believe I am filling these out correctly.

Comment: I see how editing the code can make it inconsistent and possibly lead to more confusion. Will keep this in mind next time. But save for some longer names that I've shortened here, the code here is as my code is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman HOLY MOLY please check final edit.